# Recognize a 2D geometric shape by bounds in 2D grid

Tags: java, kotlin, graphics, geometry, 2d

I'm creating an Android application using kotlin where user can draw something in a cell grid and my app should response what the shape it is.

I'm not looking for a computer vision neural network, just looking for  libraries or algorithms for Java/Kotlin

Many thank for any help!

Right now, I'm directly checking each shape, but it's becoming too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I see, try looking at the Hough transform, [Haar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_feature), and [HOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) algorithms for shape recognition in Java/Kotlin that don't need neural networks. These are flexible algorithms that can be modified to fit different forms. [OpenCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv), a popular library for image identification tasks (e.g., faces and cars), is a comprehensive library that supports these methods with its Java bindings, It's also called JavaCV. If you make some customizations, it might be useful for your purposes related to geometric form identification.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it depends on how complex the shapes are.

If it's basic shapes you can try the [$1 Unistroke Recognizer](https://depts.washington.edu/acelab/proj/dollar/index.html).
(A quick search will reveal a [Kotlin port](https://github.com/fejd/jesture))

If you're not looking for an ML model (even [RNN a-la QuickDraw](https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/) as opposed to image based) it you might want to try [Dynamic Time Warp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)(DTW).
(You can prototype using [Wekinator DTW](http://www.wekinator.org/detailed-instructions/#Dynamic_time_warping_in_Wekinator) on a desktop (even receiving data from an Android app via OSC protocol on LAN then if the protoype works well enough use the Weka framework (java based) on Android)
This is a [good detailed explanation](https://rtavenar.github.io/blog/dtw.html).

(GRT might have some interesting approaches too, though it's C++ and might need Android NDK)